# How to select all ActiveX objects in an area using a mouse in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, selection, activex

Because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19385803/1048539) with ActiveX objects changing size, I am not grouping my ActiveX objects in my Excel worksheet. Grouping them causes [my solution hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385914/1048539) to not work which is quite annoying.

However, I often times want to be able to essentially use the mouse and select a region and then select all ActiveX objects contained in the region. This would also be useful for easily selecting objects to group them initially.

Basically:

- Use mouse to select area
- Automatically select all ActiveX components in region

I'm fine with a VBA solution if needed.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have ActiveX objects, but no other Shapes on a worksheet, then loop over Shapes, examining each TopLeftCell property.  Check if any of these intersect with Selection.  If yes, then add that shape to a list.  Then Select the list of Shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub ShapePicker()
    Dim sh As Shape, st As Variant, Llist As String
    Dim ty As String
    Dim nm As String
    Dim r As Range

    Dim ary As Variant

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        ty = sh.Type
        nm = sh.name
        Set r = sh.TopLeftCell
        If ty = msoOLEControlObject Then
            If Not Intersect(r, Selection) Is Nothing Then
                If Llist = "" Then
                    Llist = nm
                Else
                    Llist = Llist & "," & nm
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    ary = Split(Llist, ",")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range((ary)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, I never thought to use Intersect like this. Pretty easily modifyable to get all objects too.

Comment: Have fun with it!